# Minimize the summation to a simple form

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, contest-math, recreational-mathematics, mathematical-physics

Could someone please help me compact the summation as in the left side of the equation below. I tried many ways but it seems to be not right,
the result I did is as the right side of the equation below

The summation is written as follows
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{i\sqrt{k^2-\big(\frac{n\pi}{b}\big)^2}c} = e^{ikc}
\end{equation}
The condition of the variables is as follows
\begin{equation}
b,c >0
\end{equation}

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does this converge or diverge anywhere ?

Comment: How did you get the sum $e^{\dot{\imath}kc}$. Show us the steps.

Comment: If there's a chance that this summation converges, I feel that you can take the value where it converges as an approx. sum.

Comment: Plus one more thing - I am a teen with no idea of what this is , so please do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @ Sam Ruben Abraham. I believe this sum will converge. See, the sum has the same character as $\sum_{n\geq K} e^{-n^2}$ for some large $K$.

Comment: Ohhh.... Thanks, @Medo ! I didn't know that I could make a guess so beautifully !

Comment: Is the $c$ inside the sqrt? Also, can you demonstrate the case for $k=0$? Seems to me that for $b$ small enough the left hand side is always real

Comment: I think the sum can be approximated using integrals,but no idea how to get such closed form.

Comment: @user619894 c is outside of the sqrt